# IE7 issue: How to expand parent div's height with dynamic content of the child div?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I need to resolve this issue on IE7 browser where the parent div's height is not expanding with dynamic content of the child div.

This is my HTML markup:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
      ....
      ....
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

This CSS vertically aligns the text in the middle and is working fine. It's just not expanding the parent div's height. The height of 80px on `.parent` is important and is set dynamically through PHP and it cannot be changed to percentage or any other value.

```
.parent { position: relative; width: 100px; height:80px; }
.middle { position: absolute; top: 50%; }
.inner { position: relative; top: -50%; padding:10px 0; width:100px; }
```

Comment: @TamilSelvan Like I wrote in my original post, I cannot use percentage on `.parent`.

Comment: If you have to set parent to 80px and nothing else how do you expect it to expand??? If this value is set because you don't want thew div to collapse if no content is available then set it to `min-height:80px`

Comment: @Vector I think min-height is not supported by IE7.

Comment: `min-height` is supported by IE7. Not by IE6.

Comment: @Spudley I just tried `min-height` but no effect.

Comment: I tried jQuery approach and it seemed to have resolved the issue. I used `height()` to read the height of `.inner` and applied that height to `.parent` with some padding on top and bottom. It seems to work perfectly using IE9's `Browser and Document Mode: IE7` and also works fine in `Quirks Mode`. Haven't tested on real IE7 browser but I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change inner class position,

false: `.inner { position: relative; top: -50%; padding:10px 0; width:100px; }`

true : `.inner { position: absolute; top: -50%; padding:10px 0; width:100px; }`

look this example: 
code : http://cdpn.io/nrcKa
full page : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nrcKa

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but it does not seem to work. I tried adding a border around `.parent`. I also duplicated the entire HTML and pasted it below the original one. It does not even work in Firefox. I've created a new pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lzfyh.